# How does @Host decorator work in injector tree

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-di

I'm trying to understand how the `@Host` decorator works **uncoupled from view-components**. So I created the following injector tree:

```
class Dependency {
}

@Injectable()
class NeedsDependency {
  constructor(@Host() public dependency: Dependency) {
    console.log(this.dependency); // outputs 'A', but I expected the error
  }
}

const parent = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([{provide: Dependency, useValue: 'A'}]);
const child = parent.resolveAndCreateChild([]);
const grandchild = child.resolveAndCreateChild([NeedsDependency]);
grandchild.get(NeedsDependency);
```

I expected to get an error, because as I understand the host for `grandchild` injector is `child`, and there is no `Dependency` provided in the `child` injector. However, when I run this code, I get `'A'` injected from the root injector. Why?

Comment: Where is `NeedsDependency` provided (`NgModel` or `Component`)?

Comment: There's no angular framework in this example, it's decoupled

Comment: Then you shouldn't expect `@Host()` to have any effect.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I'm not quite sure. Other decorators like `@Optional`, `@Self` and `@SkipSelf` ***do*** have effect when decoupled from the angular

Comment: Sure, they are independent of components also when used with Angular, but `@Host()` has a direct relation to a component. If there is no component, how can it find the injector of a component?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com it seems that it doesnt find the topmost injector https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602697/angulars-host-decorator-not-reaching-the-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Host` doesn't have semantic meaning in the context of plain `ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate` injector.

[It is just ignored](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.7/modules/%40angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.ts#L237-L248) when being used outside the compiler.

For the desired behaviour,

> I expected to get an error, because as I understand the host for grandchild injector is child, and there is no Dependency provided in the child injector.

consider using `Self` instead.

Comment: got it, thanks, I'm wondering how it's processed in terms of injector then in angular compiler

Comment: Was curious about the same thing some time ago. Classes with Directive/Component decorators get their own injectors, and constructor decorators are [additionally](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.7/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts#L712-L727) processed for them, including compiler-related Host and Attribute.

Comment: great, thanks for the links, I'll explore. I'm hoping someone will put up a book alike to `writing your own angular` for angular1

Comment: @Maximus You're welcome. Hah, this book would be a thick one, which will likely result in another overengineered framework. I'm glad when A2 works for me, but the internals give me creeps every time.

Comment: yeah, it takes time to get used to reading `TS` sources for me, but I think reading sources helps grow as a developer. The downside is that it takes immense amount of time

Answer (score 0):

> Specifies that an injector should retrieve a dependency from any injector until reaching the host element of the current component.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Host-decorator.html

Sounds to me it will look for providers and stop looking after it reached the injector of a component.

Comment: [It seems that this behaviour is not occurring up to the root.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602697/angulars-host-decorator-not-reaching-the-top)