# Angular's `@Host` decorator not reaching the top?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-decorator

In my main `app.ts` I've declared a global provider :

```
providers: [{provide: Dependency, useValue: createDependency('AppModule provider')}]
```

(*Where `createDependency` is just a function that returns a class which has a `getName()` method.*)

I also have a components :

```
    <my-app-component-3>Hello from 3</my-app-component-3>
```

Code :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app-component-3',
    template: `
        <div>Component3:
            <ng-content></ng-content>
            : <span [innerHTML]="dependency?.getName()"></span>
        </div>
    `,

})
export class Component3 {
    constructor(@Host() @Optional() public dependency: Dependency) {}
}
```

The result is:

> Component3: Hello from 3 :

But I expect the result to be :

> Component3: Hello from 3 :**AppModule provider**

Because basically the app structure is :

```
<my-app>
  <my-app-component-3>
  </my-app-component-3>
</my-app>
```

**Question:**
Why doesn't `@Host()`  match the parent provider ?

*(which is   : `providers: [{provide: Dependency, useValue: createDependency('AppModule provider')}]`)*

To my knowledge - the injector should seek for a `Dependency` in this manner :

[image]

So why doesn't it find it ?

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/qpsUzaAywtkN6JfbFXMb?p=preview)

**Notice**

I already know that if I remove `@host` - it does reach the top. My question is why adding @host - is not reaching the top - despite the fact that`my-component3` is under `my-app` !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [A curios case of the @Host decorator and Element Injectors in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-curios-case-of-the-host-decorator-and-element-injectors-in-angular-582562abcf0a) for in-depth explanation of how @Host decorator works and where Element Injectors come into this picture.

In order for it to work you should define dependencies in the **in the parent component** and using **viewProviders**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  viewProviders: [{provide: Dependency, useValue: createDependency('AppModule provider')}],
    ...
export class MyApp {}
```

Here is what the comments inside [metadata.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/cbd93fe0d0624ce5920f966027df534fd9b50b85/packages/core/src/di/metadata.ts#L252) say:

> Specifies that an injector should retrieve a dependency from any
>   injector **until** reaching the host element of the current component.

So basically it says that a host element injector and all injectors above **are not** used when resolving a dependency. So if your `MyApp` component has the following template:

```
<my-app-component-3></my-app-component-3>
```

and the resulting components tree look like this:

```
<my-app>
    <my-app-component-3></my-app-component-3>
</my-app>
```

neither `MyApp` component's injector nor App module injectors **are** used to resolve dependency for the `my-app-component-3`.

However, there's the following interesting code in the [ProviderElementContext._getDependency](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9dc310eb50f022b25184e84a3a9abc016e4a2451/packages/compiler/src/provider_analyzer.ts#L290) that performs one additional check:

```
// check @Host restriction
if (!result) {
    if (!dep.isHost || this.viewContext.component.isHost ||
       this.viewContext.component.type.reference === tokenReference(dep.token !) ||
       // this line
       this.viewContext.viewProviders.get(tokenReference(dep.token !)) != null) { <------
       result = dep;
    } else {
       result = dep.isOptional ? result = {isValue: true, value: null} : null;
    }
}
```

which basically checks if the provider is defined in the `viewProviders` and resolves it if found. That's why `viewProviders` work.

So, here is the lookup tree:

[image]

#### Usage

This decorator is mostly used for directives to resolve providers from the parent injector within the current component view. Even the [unit test is written](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/examples/core/di/ts/metadata_spec.ts#L135) only to test directives. Here is a real example from the `forms` module how it's decorator is used.

Consider this template for the `A` component:

```
<form name="b">
    <input NgModel>
</form>
```

`NgModel` directive wants to resolve a provider supplied by the `form` directive. But if the provider is not available, there's no need to go outside of a current component `A`.

So `NgModel` is defined like this:

```
export class NgModel {
    constructor(@Optional() @Host() parent: ControlContainer...)
```

While `form` directive is defined like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[formGroup]',
  providers: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }],
  ...
})
export class NgForm
```

Also, a directive can inject dependencies defined by its hosting component if they are defined with `viewProviders`. For example, if `MyApp` component is defined like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    viewProviders: [Dependency],
    template: `<div provider-dir></div>`
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

the `Dependency` will be resolved.

Comment: Isnt comp3 under app tag?

Comment: Maybe im missing something but is host element is the main one that on app?

Comment: If you edit the pkunker and change provider to viewprovider it still doesnt work. Im asking a simpe question.  Why doesnt the base provider is matched in chain. The component is inside my-app tag

Comment: @RoyiNamir, what's not clear from my answer? `@Host` decorator only resolves dependencies inside a component view and `viewProviders` of a parent component, it doesn't go up the tree to the module injector (where you defined your provider)

Comment: The thing which wasnt clear is that youve said that if i change provider to viewprovider the plunk will work. But it is not. Sorry if i missed something

Comment: @RoyiNamir You declared provider in module injector(AppModule providers array), while AngularInDepth.com tells you to declare view provider on host (App component)

Comment: @yurzui HI .Yes I can see it now(I swear I didn't notice). . **But now** I don't understnad why I msut use `viewProviders`. why doesn't the injector find the regular `provider`  (at `my-app`) ? AFAIK viewprovider is for contentChild - for not to be able to access its provider.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I see all answers above :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, the `@Host` decorator doesn't resolve dependencies defined on the host element (by the host component). The `viewProviders` is a special case as I showed in my answer

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Ok so ho come this works without any provider ?https://netbasal.com/querying-for-the-closest-parent-element-in-angular-b2554d60c47e

Comment: @RoyiNamir, first, I don't see why it wouldn't, since it's all within one component view/template. Second, the example in the article will even work without `@Host` decorator

Comment: [**To conclude : is that the case ?**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IaWV.png)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, no, that's not the case. Think of a host decorator as a decorator that limits the search for providers only within the current component template. `viewProviders` allows you also to query providers defined by current component. If you're using `@Host` decorator, the search will never go above current component template

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I added a picture. Hopefully it makes sense now

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I Appreciate it alot. Thank you. [**But to be pedantic -
 is it more accurate**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsaYE.png) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, no, `viewProviders` should be defined on `Child component`. There's no way to get providers from `AppComponent` for a directive or component inside `Child component`'s template

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the @Optional() is injecting null. I believe that one might be the culprit.

### Edit

So from your plunker I can’t seem to find an actual host for the component 3. Something like

```
   <parent-component>
       <component-3><component-3/>
<parent-component/>
```

On my understanding [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/08/20/host-and-visibility-in-angular-2-dependency-injection.html) it seems what it’s looking for.

Comment: It does. If I remove it I get an error. But I wanted to mute this error for now. The fact that it doesn't find any provider at its top - that's the culprit - and hence my question.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer with a link to a possible explanation

Comment: App is the main element which hosts component 3. So why doesn't it match it?

Comment: From the link I’ve provided I believe your problem is not having a direct parent component or directive. I believe @host will look for that. Maybe it’s a bit more specific than you were originally thinking. But I’ll dig a bit dipper when I have time

Answer (score 0):

just remove @Host() decorator from your Component 3 constructor:

```
Component({
    selector: 'my-app-component-3',
    template: `
        <div>Component3:
            <ng-content></ng-content>
            : <span [innerHTML]="dependency?.getName()"></span></div>
    `,

})
export class Component3 {
    constructor(@Optional() public dependency: Dependency) {}
}
```

Angular will take the provider from the AppModule.

Comment: I already know that. I want to understand why HOST doesn't reach the top.

Comment: That's not realted. viewProviders (which i'm not using) is a way to tell ng-content - not to know the providers of the host componenet.

Comment: It seems that when @Host() decorator is used Angular looks in all parent injectors of current element. See the unit test [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/examples/core/di/ts/metadata_spec.ts#L135)

Answer (score 0):

straight from Angular's docs on dependency injection and the Host decorator: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#qualify-dependency-lookup-with-optional-and-host

```
The @Host decorator stops the upward search at the host component.

The host component is typically the component requesting the dependency.
```

with the @Host decorator, you're telling it to only check the host component for a provider, and you're making it optional, so it's just seeing there's no provider and quitting.

In practice, the use case for the Host decorator is extremely narrow, and really only ever makes sense if you're projecting content.

Comment: _and really only ever makes sense if you're projecting content._ - that's not true, see my answer for the real use case of the `@Host` decorator

Comment: I think we've had this discussion before about how the way Angular internals use something doesn't always (or even rarely) makes sense from the perspective of a developer using the framework to build an application.